# Understanding Function using Type Members

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> sealed trait FooWrapper[A] {
     |   type B = Int
     |   type C = List[A]
     | }
defined trait FooWrapper
```

Is there any possible **reasonable** instance that will compile for this `foo` function?

```
scala> def foo[A](fooWrapper: FooWrapper[A]): fooWrapper.C = ???
foo: [A](fooWrapper: FooWrapper[A])fooWrapper.C
```

Since `FooWrapper` has no way to return a `List[A]`, I'm thinking no.

Comment: Well, `FooWrapper` doesn't really _do_ anything, it just holds some type information.

Comment: You can't pull an `A` out of thin air for an arbitrary type `A`, but you can always make a `List[A]`.

Comment: **edited for simplicity** - so why does `val xs: List[Int] = List[Nothing]()` return `xs: List[Int] = List()`? Same reason that `val x: AnyVal = 5` has type `AnyVal`?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, no?

```
sealed trait FooWrapper[A] {
   type B = Int
   type C = List[A]
}

class X(i:Int) extends FooWrapper[Int] { 
   def listify: C = List(i) 
}

def foo[A](fooWrapper: FooWrapper[A]): fooWrapper.C = fooWrapper match {
   case x: X => x.listify
   case _ => List()
}
```

Using it:

```
scala> foo(new X(2))
res1: List[Int] = List(2)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was excluding instances of `FooWrapper` when defining `foo`, i.e. not allowing `class X`.

Also, considering that you pattern matched on the type `X`, I'd recommend reading http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html.

Comment: Thanks for the link!! Maybe you have a followup question? I am still trying to wrap my head around what you want to prove with the example.